# foreach loop only showing last item outside loop

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using laravel to loop through retrieving data from an api in my controller, it all works fine but for some reason in the loop if i var_dump the data i get all that should be there but outside my loop when i pass the data to my view it doesn't work.

I am running an api request and then when i get my response i am running a secondary api request for each of the original responses. here is part of code i am having issues with.

```
foreach(array_slice($nearbysearchresults->results, 0, 5) as $result) // slicing array to limit requests 
    {
        $getplacedetails ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=". $result->place_id ."&key=XXXX";
        $placesearchresults = json_decode(file_get_contents($getplacedetails));

 var_dump($placesearchresults); // shows all 5 results

}

var_dump($placesearchresults); // shows all 1 result (outside loop).
```

Comment: Change `$placesearchresults` to `$placesearchresults[]` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: That was it!

$placesearchresults[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($getplacedetails));

thank you very much! couldnt figure out why!

Answer (score 2):

You have to change:

```
$placesearchresults = json_decode(file_get_contents($getplacedetails));
```

to:

```
$placesearchresults[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($getplacedetails));
```

Because in your current code you overwrite the value of `$placesearchresults` every time, so that's also why at the end of the loop (outside) you only have 1 result. So to get every value outside of the loop we make a array out of: `$placesearchresults` and add every value with `[]` to the array

Also that you have something to read :D See here under 'Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax ': http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

And a little quote out of that:

> An existing array can be modified by explicitly setting values in it.
>
> This is done by assigning values to the array, specifying the key in brackets. The key can also be omitted, resulting in an empty pair of brackets ([]).

```
$arr[key] = value;
$arr[] = value;
// key may be an integer or string
// value may be any value of any type
```

> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array. This practice is however discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and [] may actually stand for string access operator. It is always better to initialize variable by a direct assignment.